# Elixir: application quits immediately, or doesn't receive input when running distillery package. Why does it work that way, and how to work around it?

Tags: elixir, erlang-supervisor, distillery

I have an Elixir application that is structured the following way:

```
Application --> Supervisor --> Worker
```

The Application Module is fairly simple, it has a `use Application` and a

```
def start(_type, _args)
  MyApp.Supervisor.start_link()
end
```

The Supervisor is a bit more complicated:

```
def start_link() do
    {:ok, pid} = Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, [], name: __MODULE__)
    halt_exit(wait_for_child())
    {:ok, pid}
end

def init(data) do
    children =
    [
        worker(MyApp.Worker, [], restart: :transient)
    ]

    Supervisor.init(children, [strategy: :one_for_one])
end
```

where `halt_exit(pid)` performs a `Process.sleep(100)` and then calls itself every time it finds the process pid is still alive (or simply returns nil when pid is not alive anymore), and `wait_for_child` finds the Worker module's pid (taking into consideration that it might have to wait until it's started).

My Worker module interacts with the user using `IO.puts` and `IO.gets`. Why all this complicated unnecessary logic? It seems that

- when using mix run and omit halting exit, the application immediately dies
- when using mix release (distillery) and run `myapp.bat console` from cmd and omit halting exit, my application starts, immediately dies, and then iex is started
- when using mix release w/ `myapp.bat console` and include halting exit, my app outputs correctly, but can't receive any input (and by this I mean I can't type into the window of werl.exe)
- when using mix release w/ `myapp.bat foreground`, my app starts and *only then* there is an error in the batch file (The system cannot find the file `%get_pid_cmd%`.
  ERROR: The search filter cannot be recognised.
  '@call' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.) at which point my app terminates.
- when using mix run --no-halt (no exit-halting logic inside app), my app starts, terminates immediately, and the erlang VM remains running in the cmd window
- only when I mix run and include `halt_exit/1` does my app works as expected

From all this, I concluded that 1) the moment my application module's `start/2` returns, the app is shut down, which doesn't make much sense as Elixir is ***designed*** for applications that put the load on other processes ***instead of***, not ***besides*** the application's main module. 2) input is done through the main Application module's process (but for some reason only when run in a separate werl.exe window, seems to work fine with mix run), so I can't put any blocking-until-work-finished logic there if I want my user input.

How can I solve this, and equally importantly (so I can avoid future problems) what behaviour causes my problem? I would need to be able to run this on a computer without mix and Erlang VM installed, so my only option is to make it work with the distillery package generated, which at the moment I can't.

No amount of googling has led me to similar tactics to artificially halt exit, and no forum/tutorial I've found mentions problems with this "early-exit" so I guess the correct way to solve this would be to somehow get it not want to exit while any process is running.

Comment: I think this has something to do with the `group_leader` system in erlang. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36410816/1650580)

Answer (score 0):

> The system cannot find the file `%get_pid_cmd%`. ERROR: The search filter cannot be recognised

In the following line:

```
@for /f "delims=" %%i in (`%%get_pid_cmd%%`) do set pid=%%i
```

Try changing the backticks around `%%get_pid_cmd%%` to single quotes.

Also, in the following line:

```
set get_pid_cmd=%escript% %nodetool% eval %node_type% %node_name% -setcookie "!cookie!" "erlang:list_to_integer(os:getpid()).'
```

Change the final single quote to a double quote.

Source: https://www.bountysource.com/issues/50408118-starting-in-foreground-mode-on-windows-fails-to-get-pid-and-returns-errorlevel-1

Making these two changes in boot_win.eex, deleting the _build folder, and rebuilding worked for me.